# React Router, the url is changing but the route is not updating the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a router that has two routes and some links to switch between those routes but when I click on the Link it updates the URL but not the component. Why is it doing this?

here is the code in the return statement of my component

```
return (
  <div className="auth-form">
    <div className="auth-form__head">
      <Link to="login" className="auth-form__button">
        Login
      </Link>
      <Link to="register" className="auth-form__button">
        Register
      </Link>
    </div>
    <div className="auth-form__body">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/auth/login" component={LoginPage} />
          <Route path="/auth/register" component={SignUpPage} />
          <Redirect to="login" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: this is an easy mistake to make when using react-router. This is here to help confused learners who can't figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<Router>` needs to wrap around the Routes and the Links for it to work properly

```py
return (
    <Router>
        <div className="auth-form">
            <div className="auth-form__head">
                <Link onClick={reRender} to="login" className="auth-form__button">Login</Link>
                <Link onClick={reRender} to="register" className="auth-form__button">Register</Link>
            </div>
            <div className="auth-form__body">

                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/auth/login" component={LoginPage}/>
                        <Route path="/auth/register" component={SignUpPage}/>
                        <Redirect to="login"/>
                    </Switch>

            </div>
        </div>
    </Router>
);
```